# Integrating absolute value function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, absolute-value

I'm working on a problem drawing phase plane diagrams in my applied mathematics course.  I'm supposed to draw the phase line diagram of $x''+\vert x\vert=0.$  In the process, I get to the differential equation 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-\vert x\vert}{y}$$ and need to integrate but am apparently blanking on what this ends up being with the absolute values.  I haven't taken an ODE course for 4 years so wondered if someone could go step by step with this integration.  It'd be greatly appreciated so I can remember how and then draw my diagram.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
\int\verts{x}\,\dd x = x\verts{x} - \int x\ \sgn\pars{x}\,\dd x
=x\verts{x} - \int\verts{x}\,\dd x
$$

> $$
> \int\verts{x}\,\dd x = \half\,x\verts{x} +\ \mbox{a constant}
> $$

Answer (score 0):

Consider solving the pair of odes

> $$ \frac{dy}{dx}= \begin{cases} \frac{-x}{y},\quad x\geq 0 \\ \frac{x}{y},\quad x < 0 \end{cases}.$$

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really make any sense unless it is an initial value problem. Remember that any continous function is integrable and for $a\leq0$ and $b\geq0:$

$$\int_{a}^{b}|x| = \int_{a}^{0} -x + \int_{0}^{b}x.$$

Solve the problem accordingly.

Comment: The lack of being an IVP is why I'm stuck.  I know how to do it if it is.

Comment: Consider using the 'sgn' function as follows: $$\textup{log}(\frac{y}{k}) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot (x^{2}\cdot \textup{sgn}(x)-x_{0}^{2}\cdot \textup{sgn}(x_{0}}))$$.