# integrate absolute value of trig function?

Tags: integration

Given a function y= |sin x|
What would the integral from x=0 to 10 evaluate to?

I read this
[Integrating absolute value function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/551036/integrating-absolute-value-function)

but do not know exactly how to apply it.

I guess I could just start with this function

y=((sin(x))^2)^.5

Comment: I think y=((sin(x))^2)^.5 is hot helpful.

Comment: break up the limits of integrals.